# Setup ODBC connection between Firebird and Oracle

Tags: oracle, odbc, firebird

I would like to set up a connection between a Firebird database and an Oracle database. I know, to create an Oracle dblink, I need to configure the ODBC driver for Firebird.

I have installed the Firebird ODBC driver and set up the connection as below, but I have an error:

> gds32.dll failed to load

I haven't found the gds32.dll file anywhere - where to get it, do I need to install anything else? I do the ODBC configurations on an Oracle database server, while the Firebird database runs on a different server.

[image]

Comment: The error message is a bit confusing, because the error reports a legacy library name that is tried as a fallback, but the problem is that you do not have the Firebird client library (fbclient.dll, or the fallback, gds32.dll) installed. You can install it with the Firebird server installer by choosing the client installation.

Answer (score 1):

You must set Firebird client library (fbclient.dll) name (and path to it if you didn't install it into system directory or added the path to the system PATH variable) in field "Client".

PS: And of course you must have the Firebird client installed on the host where you set up connection.

Comment: Where can I find Firebird client? Should I install Server Package: https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-4-0/ ?  Is it possible to choose to install the client during the installation server package?

Comment: Run installer and choose "client only install" - @user3198135